# How to loop through child nodes using XSLT1.0

Tags: loops, xslt, xslt-1.0, child-nodes

I have below xml fragment. I need to loop through all the child nodes based on some condition and print the node name.

```
  <Parentnode>
        <Date>01-Jan-2017</Date>
        <Aab>w</Aab>
        <Abc>g</Abc>
        <Anb>16</Anb>
        <Amr>25</Amr>
  </Parentnode>
```

I need to output all the child node name which is not `<Date>` node and all the child node names whose value is not 'g'.

Something like this.

```
<Parentnode>
   <Code>Aab</Code>
   <Code>Anb</Code>
   <Code>Amr</Code>
</Parentnode>
```

Request you to help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="Parentnode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::Date or .='g')]">
            <!-- do something -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```